# how to print words which is separated with delimiters using batch file?

Tags: comments, dos

I am very new to DOS Comments.
I have a text file which has so many entries but it s separated by a delimeter
(Ex: Hi; conf.txt; 161; new team)

I want to print each and every separation in a separate line.

Ex:
The output should be
Hi
conf.txt
161
new team

Can you guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
  set str=%%a
  echo !str:;=!
))>file.tmp

move file.tmp file.txt >nul
```

Where 'file.txt' is the name of your text file (you need to change it in both places in the batch file).